# Why are separable and normal field extensions so called?

Tags: soft-question, field-theory, galois-theory

To my understanding: A separable extension $K/F$ is one in which the minimal polynomial of every $\alpha\in K$ has no multiple roots. A normal extension $K/F$ is one in which some polynomial $f\in F[X]$ splits over $K$.

Is there any reason why these concepts are so called, or are they just arbitrary names?

Comment: It would be delightful if every property had a name that was reasonably descriptive. In the case of “normal”, this is unfortunately not the case.

Comment: Your definition of “normal” is not right. It’s that **every** $F$-polynomial with a root in $K$ splits over $K$. According to your criterion, any extension would be normal, since I offer $X-1$ as an $F$-polynomial that splits over $K$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always thought, but this is not a historic answer, that "separable" comes from the fact that the roots are "separate" in the sense that there are no repeated roots.

This is in line what I just found when searching [Keith Conrad in his lecture notes writes](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/separable1.pdf):

> The term 'separable' comes from distinctness of the roots: they are separate in the sense that there are no multiple roots.

For "normal" I would say it is pretty arbitrary except that the name should somehow convey that these are the good/well-behaved/regular extension. Sometimes a normal extension is also call quasi-Galois.

Answer (score 0):

This is very much so a stab in the dark (read: definitely not historical) but sometimes when people say "normal" extension they mean Galois. Similarly, over perfect fields (all extensions are separable; e.g. char 0) normal extensions <-> Galois extensions.

If we have a Galois extension $K/F$, $F$ perfect (is this necessary?), normal subgroups of $\operatorname{Gal}(K/F)$ correspond to normal subextensions of $K/F$.

Comment: You’re right in this sense, that normal extensions correspond to normal subgroups of the Galois group. If it happened that normal subgroups were named first, you might imagine that normality of extensions was accordingly named. (You can see that I know no history.)